# connecting (bridging) two networks

Tags: linux, networking, ppp, bridge

I would like to connect (bridge) two networks (ppp0 and eth2).
Normally you would do this with brctl but one of the network-interface is a ppp-device so it won't work (ppp can't transport ppp-frames).
What I could do, is enable ip-forwarding but that is not enough as I want traffic from that ppp-device only go to eth2 and vice versa. NAT is fine. Another problem is that as far as I know you cannot push routing information to ppp-clients?
Any help is appreciated! (solutions that work with windows/mac/android clients would be nice but not absolutely required)

Comment: so i would like to bridge on ip level

Answer (score 6):

You can't bridge ethernet and PPP because they are different layer two protocols, and incompatible ones at that.

- PPP, as it's name implies is a direct point to point link. It doesn't know the concept of multiple hosts on the local link.
- Ethernet on the other hand can have any number (well, lots) of other hosts on the local link.

Reconciling this directly is impossible.

However, there is something *else* you can do: encapsulate the ethernet packets using an IP-in-IP tunnel between the two PPP endpoints then use `brctl` to bridge the ethernet and tunnel interfaces.

Read more in the [IP-in-IP HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html).

Comment: Note that if security is a concern use a VPN tunnel instead.

Comment: but would it be possible to bridge on ip level?

Comment: No. IP is layer 3. Bridging is at layer 2.

Comment: So you never call it a bridge if you would connect somehing on IP layer?

Comment: No, I don't. A **bridge** is a device that connects L2 (ether) networks. A **router** or **gateway** is a device that connects L3 (IP) networks. And the question asks explicitly about brctl and explicitly not IP forwarding.

Comment: More of an unrelated question that I got the answer for. Thx,